# OrientDB data write from CSV files

Tags: csv, orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb-etl

I was researching OrientDB and it in a single host mode it did not show great performance results. I need to create the table in OrientDB by importing the records from CSV file.

Is there any specific command to write single table CSV file into OrientDB except for the ETL import?

In comparison, there is LoadCSV command for Neo4j which allows importing single file except for the import tool.

Answer (score 1):

OrientDB Teleporter is a tool that synchronizes an RDBMS to OrientDB database. You can use Teleporter to:

- Import your existing RDBMS to OrientDB
- Keep your OrientDB database synchronized with changes from the RDBMS. In this case, the database on RDBMS remains the primary and the database on OrientDB a synchronized copy. Synchronization is one way, so all the changes in OrientDB database will not be propagated to the RDBMS
  Teleporter is fully compatible with several RDBMS that has a JDBC driver: we successfully tested Teleporter with Oracle, SQLServer, MySQL, PostgreSQL and HyperSQL. Teleporter manages all the necessary type conversions between the different DBMSs and imports all your data as Graph in OrientDB.

**NOTE:** This feature is available both for the OrientDB Enterprise Edition and the OrientDB Community Edition. But beware: in community edition, you can migrate your source relational database but you cannot enjoy the synchronize feature, only available in the enterprise edition.

For more information: https://orientdb.com/docs/2.2.x/Teleporter-Home.html

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Thanks. However, I am more interested in import from files and not from RDBMS

Comment: Through the side tab you can choose to import from JSON file, for example

Comment: Sorry, if I'm not following. You mean through the side tab of this Teleporter tool?

Comment: Yes, if you press Teleporter than, ETL tab, you can import a JSON file, if this can help you

Comment: Thank you very much. I will try that out